# Is there a way to find out why tmux crashed

Tags: tmux

I am trying to shift from using VNC to tmux. My tmux keeps crashing at least once in a week and I am clueless why this happens. VNC rarely crashed and this weekly crash is a strong detrimental for me to completely switch.

Is there a way I can find out the reason tmux crashes ? My .tmux.conf is pretty simple

```
 #Don't show the green ribbon below
 set -g status off                                                                                                                                                                                           
 #Select panes by mouse click                                                                                                                                                                                
 set -g mouse-select-pane on                                                                                                                                                                                 
 #enable scrolling by mouse in tmux                                                                                                                                                                          
 set-window-option -g mode-mouse on                                                                                                                                                                          
 #enable resize of pane by mouse                                                                                                                                                                             
 set -g mouse-resize-pane on
```

I use iterm2 with terminal mode set to 256 color and heavily use vim plugins and colorschemes(Lid, nerdtree, tagbar, indentLine, molokai etc.,). To adjust terminal color I had following setting in my .vimrc but I am not sure if these are in any way related to tmux crash

```
set t_ut=
set t_Co=256
```

Also, I have enabled mouse in my vim `set mouse=a`

Is there a way to find why my tmux session is crashing ?

EDIT: Attaching the final logs from my tmux-server

```
found key 0x1001: ""
input_parse: ' ground
input_c0_dispatch: '
input_parse: ' ' ground
input_parse: ' ground
input_c0_dispatch: '
keys are 1 ()
complete key  0x1001
writing key 0x1001
found key 0x1001: ""
input_parse: ' ground
input_c0_dispatch: '
input_parse: ' ' ground
input_parse: ' ground
input_c0_dispatch: '
keys are 1 ()
complete key  0x1001
writing key 0x1001
found key 0x1001: ""
input_parse: ' ground
input_c0_dispatch: '
input_parse: ' ' ground
input_parse: ' ground
input_c0_dispatch: '
keys are 1 ()
complete key  0x1001
writing key 0x1001
found key 0x1001: ""
input_parse: '' ground
input_c0_dispatch: '
got 5 from client 6
writing 4 to client 6
got 13 from client 6
```

Comment: Can you start `tmux` using `tmux -vvvv` ? It will give you a logfile in the same directory called `tmux-[...].log`. Try to reproduce the crash and as soon as it crashes, post the last X lines of your error log here :)!

Comment: @polym I have started tmux as follows `tmux -vvv -S default new-session -s $USER` I will paste the log during the next crash

Comment: @polym Here is the output of tmux server after it crashed.         `user@server> tail tmux-server-33131.log 
input_parse: ' ' ground
keys are 1 ()
complete key  0x2
keys are 1 (d)
complete key d 0x64
cmdq 0x12c4460: detach-client (client 8)
writing 1 to client 8
got 5 from client 8
writing 4 to client 8
lost client 8
user@server>`

Comment: can you edit your question and put more of the logs (server and client) e.g. `tail -n200` ?

Comment: @polym I have attached the logs to the question after tmux has crashed

Comment: For information if it may help someone.
I got my tmux server crashed today just typing ^l (Ctrl-l) in the Konsole that is just a refresh of the terminal display. Avoid ^l.

Answer (score 20):

I found this in the readme on the `tmux` GitHub page.

> For debugging, running `tmux` with `-v` or `-vv` will generate server and
> client log files in the current directory.

In other words, unless you explicitly told it to log, it won't.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing crashes related to my `.tmux.conf`, this is what I did to figure out:

Run *tmux* to get client, server and output log files.

`tmux -vv`

`cat tmux-out-*.log`

This will give you a hint of what is going on, if for example your config file wasn't parsed properly and the program has crashed before you were able read something.

Client and server logs could be accessed this way:

`cat tmux-client-*.log`

`cat tmux-server-*.log`

Comment: Seeing that `tmux -vvv` has [already been mentioned in another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493355/117549), I'd like to suggest that you edit that question with the commands to display the client & server logs.  Simply click [the edit link on that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/493355/edit) and add the missing commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may/will depend on the distro you're using, and whether or not debug/dev packages for tmux are installed, and whether or not it would dump core (if the OS settings permit it to).  If it dumps core, and you have a debug version, you should be able to narrow the reason for the failure down quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

My tmux session just crashed when I changed the status bar settings (set -g status off )
Apparently there is some instability related to the status bar reconfiguration.
c.f https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1854

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/418178)

Comment: @athul: Welcome to the Stack Exchange “Late answers” review queues! … I agree that the above is a weak answer because it is an ‘‘I’m having this problem, too’’ comment with a guess as to the cause and no remedy.  But it’s not a link-only answer.  A rule of thumb is to imagine the post with the link(s) removed.  If there’s nothing left but fluff (like “See this”), then it’s a link-only answer.  But the above is what “include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference” *looks like.*

Comment: okay understood.But only thing other than the link is i am too facing issue but not sure same.So i thought link only answer may be the right one.